# How to make a mac installer for electron app from windows

Tags: javascript, json, github, electron

How can I make a mac installer for electron app from a windows pc?
When I run `npm make` it making a windows installer only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the app to be *signed* it has to be done on a MacOS, and also requires giving money each year to Apple: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/code-signing

If you are only distributing to Mac users who trust you, i.e. who are willing to ignore the security warning they get shown, then you can build for Mac on any of Mac, Windows and Linux. [Electron-packager](https://electron.github.io/electron-packager/main/) can do this.

Comment: Well, there's a caveat there. Whilst you can cross-build the `.app`, you cannot cross-build the `.dmg` (which, more traditionally speaking, is something like an "installer" for the Mac world, if I'm not mistaken) because the filesystem for this image file is proprietary and cannot be created without a Mac. (At least not with `electron-installer-dmg` and I also had no luck using Electron Builder.)

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner We make a zip, and distribute that. But, suitable for expert users only.  Otherwise, I think the answer to the OP's question is it can't be done without a Mac.